# Render a calendar & appointments with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, calendar, momentjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a calendar for each user that looks like that
(ignore the styling it is not the final result) :

[image]

I have an array of appointments coming from the backend, I wanna render them where they should be based on the date and time.

I can't find a good practice for that, I was thinking to use data attributes and change them after the appointments are loaded but the React website says to avoid it.
So the only way I can think of is running on the appointments array every time I render a cell (I don't use table but div) and check if the time equals.
I try to avoid it because it seems to me a bad practice, every rendered DIV will have to run on the appointments array and check if one of them matches by timestamp.

Is there any way to render them after the calendar is rendered? like that I can change the specific cells and avoid unnecessary loops.

I use React Hooks & Redux for the frontend.

Edit:
Here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import moment from 'moment';

function Calendar() {
    const calendarFromStore = useSelector(state => state.calendar);
    const [calendar, setCalendar] = useState({});
    const [settings, setSettings] = useState({
        currentWeek: [],
        diffWeeks: 0,
        totalAppointments: []
}); 

useEffect(() => {
    setCalendar(calendarFromStore);
    setSettings({ ...settings, currentWeek: getCurrentWeek })
}, [calendarFromStore]);

useEffect(() => {
    setSettings({ ...settings, currentWeek: getCurrentWeek })
}, [settings.diffWeeks])

const getCurrentWeek = useMemo(() => {
    let currentDate = moment().add(settings.diffWeeks, 'weeks');
    let days = [];
    for (let i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
        days.push(moment(currentDate).subtract(i, 'days').format('dddd DD/MM/YY'));
    }
    for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        days.push(moment(currentDate).add(i, 'days').format('dddd DD/MM/YY'));
    }
    return days;
}, [settings.diffWeeks])

const daysHeader = useMemo(() => {
    if (!settings.currentWeek) return;
    return settings.currentWeek.map((day, i) =>
        <div className={`day-title ${i === 3 && !settings.diffWeeks ? 'today' : ''}`} key={day}>
            <span className="day">{day.substring(0, day.indexOf(' '))}</span>
            <span className="date">{day.substring(day.indexOf(' '))}</span>
        </div>)
}, [settings.currentWeek, settings.diffWeeks]);

const timeline = useMemo(() => {
    let currTime = '10:00';
    const stopTime = '19:00';
    const interval = 15;
    let timesArr = [];
    while (currTime !== stopTime) {
        timesArr.push(currTime);
        currTime = moment(currTime, 'HH:mm').add(interval, 'minute').format('HH:mm');
    }
    setSettings({ ...settings, totalAppointments: timesArr })
    return timesArr;
}, [])

const convertStringToTimestamp = (day, time) => {
    const fixedDay = day.substring(day.indexOf(' '));
    return moment(`${fixedDay} ${time}`, 'DD/MM/YY HH:mm').unix();
}

const calendarApts = useMemo(() => {
    if (!settings.currentWeek) return;
    return settings.currentWeek.map(day =>
        <div className="line" key={day}>
            {timeline.map(time =>
                <div key={`${day} ${time}`}
                    time={convertStringToTimestamp(day, time)} onClick={() => console.log(day, time)}>
                </div>)
            }
        </div>
    )
}, [settings.currentWeek, timeline])

useMemo(() => {
    calendar.appointments && calendar.appointments.map(apt => apt);
}, [calendar.appointments])

const changeWeeks = val => {
    setSettings({ ...settings, diffWeeks: !val ? 0 : settings.diffWeeks + val })
}

return (
    <div className="calendar-container">
        <div className="navigation">
            <div className="last-buttons">
                <button onClick={() => changeWeeks(-5)}>Last month</button>
                <button onClick={() => changeWeeks(-1)}>Last week</button>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => changeWeeks(0)}>Current Week</button>
            <div className="next-buttons">
                <button onClick={() => changeWeeks(1)}>Next week</button>
                <button onClick={() => changeWeeks(5)}>Next month</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="calendar-header">
            {daysHeader}
        </div>
        <div className="calendar-content">
            <div className="calendar-timeline">
                {timeline.map(time => <div key={time}><span>{time}</span></div>)}
            </div>
            <div className="calendar-vertical-lines">
                {calendarApts}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default Calendar;
```

Comment: Hey danivegas, can You show some code? - i think it should be to correlate the cell of data with paremeters from backend. What is the structure of schema? I mean, when apointment is on 10:45, and 10.01, then it should be rendered in cell - [5,4]. For it possible to use loop or something. How you create this frontend? It's an array or table?

Comment: Added my code, the appointments is an array of objects, each object has an id, starts (timestamp) and client name.

Comment: For now, every appointment should be the same as the user decides, if the appointment time is 15m and a client submits an appointment, it should be rendered on that exact cell, for example from 10:30 to 10:45. unlike other calendars that you can set the appointment from 10:35 to 10:50 and the time is between... for now I'd rather not go down to such a resolution

Comment: Ok, from what I see, the key are day and time parameters (in calendarApts) - to display backend data in the right place - you need information about the date and time of the meeting. - moreover - I recommend breaking the components into smaller ones

Comment: Do you have a backend structure or do you need to create it? data is being read from another api? Is the user able to create events?

Comment: can you explain a little bit more? I have the information about the meeting (starting time - timestamp). But how can I render the exact cell to contain the meeting info except checking the appointments array every time I render a cell inside calendarApts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205684/discussion-between-danivegas-and-piotr-zak).